# Multiple Buttons calling for separate AJAX functions i n1 page

Tags: php, ajax

When I have many buttons 1 page, how do I identify different buttons that make different AJAX requests? See code/script below (button1 to switch_on.php, button2 to switch_off.php). How do I link the specific button to a specific function within 1 page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Update MySQL</h2></div>
   <button switch-ONid=“1” class="loadButton">Switch ON</button>
   <button switch-OFFid=“0” class="loadButton">Switch OFF</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "switch_on.php",
     success: function(result){
       $("#div1").html(result);
      }
   });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         url: "switch_off.php",
         success: function(result){
           $("#div1").html(result);
          }
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `id` for them :

```html
<button id="btnOn" class="loadButton">Switch ON</button>
<button id="btnOff" class="loadButton">Switch OFF</button>
```

Your javascript :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnOn").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
        url: "switch_on.php",
        success: function(result){
           $("#div1").html(result);
        }
      });
   });


    $("#btnOff").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: "switch_off.php",
           success: function(result){
             $("#div1").html(result);
           }
        });
    });

});

</script>
```